# Salesforce Toolkit for .Net with silverlight 5

Tags: .net

I am creating a application with Silverlight 5 in which I have to communicate with Salesforce APIs.

Currently I used Salesforce toolkit for .net (version 1.2.1) by I am gettting error after using authentication method as -

> The base class or interface 'System.Object' in assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' referenced by type
>   'Salesforce.Common.AuthenticationClient' could not be resolved.
>   System.runtime dll is referenced my application.

And Latest version of toolkit is even not installing in application. There is some compatibility issue with silverlight 5.

As per github and blogs Salesforce Toolkit is compatible with Silverlight 5. I installed it using nuget package manager.

Any idea to fix this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is NOT compatible with silverlight.

I tried to remove the unsupported references, but then I get a permission exception. This is due to the fact that Salesforce didn't put the xml policy file on the server that would allow cross domain request.

The only way to bypass this limitation is to NOT use webservices but to send string (example: xml or json) instead, via javascript. That works but it is really a dirty workaround....