# Salesforce rest api with Silverlight 5

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I want to use **salesforce rest api** with **Silverlight** application. But I am getting security error.

Is there any way to allow and configure ClientAccessPolicy for salesforce rest api service.

Comment: Ramashanker, if you do not agree that this is a duplicate question, please extend the amount of details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I'm afraid that this is not possible.
See my answer here for a dirty workaround: [Salesforce Toolkit for .Net with silverlight 5](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105362/salesforce-toolkit-for-net-with-silverlight-5)